# is it possible: custom trayicon balloon?

Tags: qt, winapi

I want to do custom cloud (system balloon) as i paint in attach picture.
Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The [QSystemTrayIcon](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qsystemtrayicon.html#details) class has a simple balloon message option available ([QSystemTrayIcon::showMessage](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qsystemtrayicon.html#showMessage)) but it only provides a few icon choices and a text message. If you want to customize it beyond that, you would have to write a custom `QWidget` and display that or use some OS specific library calls if they are available.

The source code for `QSystemTrayIcon` includes the code for the balloon widget that it uses so that may help with writing your own.

Answer (score 1):

The docs are a bit confuzzling, but I'm fairly sure you need to use [NOTIFYICONDATA.hBalloonIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773352%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Vista or better required.